# How to create time in java?

Tags: java

I've made a simple code with time but I want the it to also be moving, not just printing it out. Hope you guys can help me on this.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[]args){
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
}
}
```

Comment: If by "moving" you mean update every second, then you need to re-print it every second! Once something is printed, it's printed.

Comment: You don't need Calendar, btw. You need `dateFormat.format(new Date())`

Comment: Yes I want it to update every second

Comment: DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(System.currentTimeMillis()));

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[]args){
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  while(true) {
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

This makes your code run forever, "pausing" for 1000 milliseconds (1 second) after every print.

Note that:

1. It will wait "at least" 1000 milliseconds, but hardly exactly 1000 milliseconds. Should be good enough for your goal though.
2. It will print the time on a new line at every iteration. Actually overwriting the line in the console is far more complicated, as you need to interact with the console cursor.
3. You'll need to force the shutdown of the program, as this is an infinite loop. You can (usually) press Ctrl+c in the console running it.